# Postgresql Group By and create columns for different values

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm using Postgresql and have this table:

| device_id | date | variable_name | pulses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-29 | height | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-03-29 | speed | 20 |
| 1 | 2021-03-30 | height | 30 |
| 1 | 2021-03-30 | temperature | 40 |
| 2 | 2021-03-29 | height | 50 |
| 2 | 2021-03-29 | acceleration | 60 |
| 2 | 2021-03-29 | distance | 70 |

And want to query so I Group By device_id and date, and create columns by variable_name, so the table expected is:

| device_id | date | height | speed | temperature | acceleration | distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-29 | 10 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-03-30 | 30 | 0 | 40 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-03-29 | 50 | 0 | 0 | 60 | 70 |

Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: [Crosstab questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+and+%28%5Bpivot%5D+or+%5Bcrosstab%5D%29)

Comment: What's the expected to happen if some later adds a color variable_name? Ignore, or automatically add a color column to the result?

Comment: Ignore, or I would have to mannually add the new variable_name as another column

Comment: You can use `case` expressions to do _conditional aggregation_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in addition to crosstab, there is a more direct way through `case` operator

```
Select device_id, date, 
       Sum(Case When variable_name='height' Then pulses Else 0 End) As height,
       Sum(Case When variable_name='speed' Then pulses Else 0 End) As speed,
       Sum(Case When variable_name='temperature' Then pulses Else 0 End) As temperature,
       Sum(Case When variable_name='acceleration' Then pulses Else 0 End) As acceleration,
       Sum(Case When variable_name='distance' Then pulses Else 0 End) As distance
From Tbl
Group by device_id, date
Order by device_id, date
```

Data Output:

```
device_id| date                 | height | speed | temperature | acceleration | distance
_________|______________________|________|_______|_____________|______________|_________
        1| 2021-03-29 00:00:00  |      10|     20|            0|             0|        0
        1| 2021-03-30 00:00:00  |      30|      0|           40|             0|        0
        2| 2021-03-29 00:00:00  |      50|      0|            0|            60|       70
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm just wondering about why did you use Sum?

Comment: @TOMAS RIQUELME GAJARDO You are welcome. Aggregation should be used, because otherwise you will get as many rows for the device_id and date values as there are different variable names.