# How can I combine two virtual tables from one table, assigning half the data to a new column, without losing data

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, outer-join, self-join

I have a table formatted as such

| age | height | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 180 | george |
| 16 | 192 | phil |
| 20 | 148 | lily |
| 17 | 187 | george |
| 19 | 196 | phil |
| 24 | 147 | lily |
| 19 | 190 | george |
| 20 | 199 | phil |
| 22 | 148 | lily |
| 21 | 190 | george |
| 27 | 197 | phil |
| 60 | 138 | lily |

I need to get the data into a format where a column exists for each name, which contains the height of the individual, with the row containing blanks or nulls for the other columns, except age and that users height

I have tried various combinations of unions and joins, but I dont seem to be able to get new columns with unions, and I dont seem to be able to join and retain data since in reality none of the ages overlap (and I need to preserve all data, so the ON clause is giving me trouble)

The closest query I have been able to get data from is

```
with aaa as (
  SELECT age, height as "george" from table1 where name in ($GRAFANA_VARIABLE1),
    bbb as SELECT age, height as "lily" from table1 where name in ($GRAFANA_VARIABLE2)
)
SELECT aaa.age, george, lily, from aaa FULL JOIN bbb on bbb.age = aaa.age
```

This results in

| age | george | lily |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 180 |  |
| NULL | NULL | 148 |
| 17 | 187 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 147 |
| 19 | 190 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 148 |
| 21 | 190 | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 138 |

which loses my age data for lily.  I know Im close, I can also retain the age data in a 2nd column with another query where I rename bbb's age to age2, but for the purposes of the plotting tool I am using, the x-axis data must all exist in a single column, with each series on the y axis being its own column as well

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) PS Please use standard spelling & punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
Select age, 
       Sum(Case When name='$GRAFANA_VARIABLE1' Then height Else NULL End) As George,
       Sum(Case When name='$GRAFANA_VARIABLE2' Then height Else NULL End) As Lily
From table1 WHERE name in ($GRAFANA_VARIABLE1) or name in ($GRAFANA_VARIABLE2)
Group by age
Order by age
```

did the trick for me.  Im not sure how the sums would output if items were not unique.

Based off of answers found here: [Helpful question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380431/postgresql-group-by-and-create-columns-for-different-values)